# How to stop animation elements moving on top of other element

Tags: html, css, angular

I have implemented animation on a list. List should move horizontally on the screen. There is a div element for information i.e. waiting token.

List should not cross that div.

here goes my code:

```css
.list_wrapper__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 0;
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: animate_opp_2 25s linear infinite;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.list_wrapper__content___item {
  height: 5vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: grey;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

@keyframes animate_opp_2 {
  0% {
    left: 10;
    transform: translate(20%);
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%);
  }
}

.header {
  height: 140px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="list_wrapper">
  <div class="header"> Waiting Tokens</div>
  <div class="list_wrapper__content">
    <div class="list_wrapper__content___item" *ngFor="let item of ListItems">
      {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Stackblitz for the same:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pvmjdz?file=src/app/app.component.css

Looks like I am missing something. Any help will be highly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an image of a small mockup of what you would like it to look like?

Comment: @TerekJanczik Added image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all `list_wrapper__content___item` with

```
<div class="list_wrapper__content___item" *ngFor="let item of ListItems">
      {{item}}
</div>
```

```css
.list_wrapper {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  min-width: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  z-index:1
}

.list_wrapper__content {
  animation: animate_opp_2 25s linear infinite;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.list_wrapper__content___item {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 1%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: grey;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}

@keyframes animate_opp_2 {
  0% {
    left: 10;
    transform: translate(20%);
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="list_wrapper">
  <div class="header"> Waiting Tokens</div>
  <div class="list_wrapper__content">
    <div class="list_wrapper__content___item">
      1000
    </div>
    <div class="list_wrapper__content___item">
      1001
    </div>
    <div class="list_wrapper__content___item">
      1002
    </div>
    <div class="list_wrapper__content___item">
      1003
    </div>
    <div class="list_wrapper__content___item">
      1004
    </div>
    <div class="list_wrapper__content___item">
      1005
    </div>
    <div class="list_wrapper__content___item">
      1006
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

Answer (score -1):

you put an animation on your wrapper div, if you want to stop the animation right before

```
<div class="header"> Waiting Tokens</div>
```

you should put your animation on .list_wrapper__content___item

i slightly modified your css

```
.list_wrapper {
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.list_wrapper__content {
  /* position: absolute; */
  left: 0;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  /* margin-left: 10%; */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list_wrapper__content___item {
  height: 5vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: grey;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  animation: animate_opp_2 5s linear infinite;
}
```

working example:
https://angular-ivy-5egh19.stackblitz.io

Comment: stackblitz doesnot work